# Open Identity and OAuth

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid, openid-connect

Lets assume I have application A and application B. I also have a SSO application. Assuming that a user can log on to application a and b using the same credentials, when they sign up using the SSO. Now on application a's table how do i store information regarding the authorized user? Do I store the OpenID token in my app's a database and populate the user information using that id as a key? I am confused on this.

For example in a traditional login system, you would use the account id for the user to link data stored in the orders table. How would you do a similar thing?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question - user migration is not well explained in most articles. When your back end receives a request you will typically need to match up to your product data on either the User ID in the access token or via the email from the Authorization Server's user info.

I have a write up on how I've managed this in the past that may help: https://authguidance.com/2017/10/02/user-data/